# Getting "KeyError: 'example'" when reading session values in a different route

Tags: python, session, flask

I have a problem because I want to include values in the session. When I save the values in one `app.route` and later I need to go to another link and use this value, I get a `KeyError`. What am I doing wrong?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from OPTYMALIZACJA import OPTYMALIZACJA

app = Flask(__name__)  
app.secret_key = "abc" 
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'memcached' 

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def first():
    # calculation instructions
    session['example'] = 'example1'
    return render_template('index.html')
    
@app.route('/export')
def second():
    s = session['example']
    print(s)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

In `index.html` I have a link to the `localhost/export` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is working as expected.

Here are some things you can check:

1. Make sure the key you used to save in `session` in `first` is the *exact* same key you used to get from `session` in `second`. I know your sample code already shows the same key `example`, but your *actual* code may not be using the same key or it was somehow removed from `session`.

   You can check the contents of `session` by printing `session.items()` (like a `dict`):

   ```
   print(session.items())
   print(session['example'])

   # 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2019 16:03:52] "GET /export HTTP/1.1" 200 -
   # dict_items([('example', 'example1')])
   # example1
   ```
2. Make sure you are accessing the correct route (`first`) that updates `session`. For example, while I was testing your sample code, I was accidentally refreshing */export* instead of accessing the correct route at */*.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, it's usually good practise to use `get` to prevent KeyErrors like that, so instead of `s = session['example']` do `s = session.get('example', 'default value')`

```py
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)  
app.secret_key = "abc" 
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'memcached' 

@app.route('/',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def first():
    #calculation instructions
    session['example'] = 'example1'
    return session['example']

@app.route('/export')
def second():
    s = session.get('example', 'YourDefaultValueHere')
    print(s)
    return session['example']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```